# Why are all iterations in a loop parallelized using OpenMP schedule(dynamic) given to one thread? (MSVS 2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, scheduling, openmp

**Direct Question:** I've got a simple loop with, what can be, a computationally intensive function.  Let's assume that each iteration takes the same amount of time (so load balancing *should* be easy).

```
#pragma omp parallel
{

#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
for ( int i=0; i < 30; i++ )
{
     MyExpensiveFunction();
}

}  // parallel block
```

Why are all of the iterations assigned to a single thread?  I can add a:

```
std::cout << "tID = " << omp_get_thread_num() << "\n\n";
```

and it prints a bunch of zeros with only the last iteration assigned to thread 1.

**My System:** I must support cross compiling.  So I'm using gcc 4.4.3 & 4.5.0 and they both work as expected, but for MS 2010, I see the above behavior where 29 iterations are assigned to thread 0 and one iteration is assigned to thread 1.

**Really Odd:**  It took me a bit to realize that this might simply be a scheduling problem.  I google'd and found [this website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5aw0hdf%28VS.80%29.aspx), which if you skip to the bottom has an example with what must be *auto-generated* output.  All iterations using **dynamic** and **guided** scheduling are assigned to thread zero??!?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, this is because the OMP implementation in Visual Studio decided that you did nowhere near enough work to merit putting it on more than one thread. If you simply increase the quantity of iterations, then you may well find that the other threads have more utilization. Dynamic scheduling means that the implementation only forks new threads if it needs them, so if it doesn't need them, it doesn't make them or assign them work.

Comment: I think that in general, you're correct - so I accepted your answer, but I wanted to add that after extensive testing, I was able to determine that the noted odd behavior was in fact due to locking my process to a specific set of cores.  In Windows, I was using the SetProcessAffinityMask -- I definitely had enough cores to accommodate my threads (I called omp_set_max_threads(4) on a dual quad-core), but for whatever reason the affinity was messing up the OpenMP allocation.  When I removed the affinity (keeping omp_set_max_threads(4)), I saw the expected allocation which matched gcc.

Comment: @M. Tibbits: Normally, you mention that kind of thing in the question :P

Answer (score 1):

1. If each iteration takes the same amount of time, then you actually don't need a dynamic scheduling which causes more scheduling overhead than static scheduling policies. (static, 1) and (static) should be okay.
2. Could you let me know the length of each iteration? Regarding the example you cited (MSDN's example for schedulings), it is because the amount of work of each iteration is so small, so the first thread just got almost work. If you really increase the work of each iteration (at least an order of millisecond), then you will see the differences.

I did a lot of experiments related to OpenMP scheduling policies. MSVC's implementation of dynamic scheduling works well. I'm pretty sure your work in each iteration was too small.